# How do use a sub-query within a query in SQL?

Tags: sql, subquery

I'm fairly new to SQL and am having trouble generating the correct information. I have a data set with FinishedGood part numbers and ProductClassCode, among other things. What I am looking for is all FinishedGood part numbers with multiple ProductClassCode's, one of which is 'WU'. I can run a query to find all ProductClassCode's equal to WU:

```
select finished_good
from FFTGGM.data_attributes_ext
where prodclass_cd = 'WU'
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to use that query to compare it to all FinishedGood's to generate a list of FinishedGood's with a ProdClasssCode of 'WU' AND something else. I know I can use it as a sub-query, but I'm unsure of how to get the correct order for the look up. Any advice?

-Edit-

Some sample data:

[image: sample data]

Comment: Please post sample data and the desired result based on this data.

Comment: What in the Primary Key for FFTGGM.data_attributes_ext?

Comment: I've added some sample/result data. I don't know what a Primary Key is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an IN clause or an EXISTS clause:

```
select *
from FFTGGM.data_attributes_ext
where finished_good in
(
  select distinct finished_good
  from FFTGGM.data_attributes_ext
  where prodclass_cd = 'WU'
)
```

or

```
select *
from FFTGGM.data_attributes_ext A
where 
EXISTS (
  select finished_good
  from FFTGGM.data_attributes_ext B
  where A.finished_good=B.finished_good
    and prodclass_cd = 'WU'
)
```

If you only want finished goods which have 'WU" and also have another non-WU product-class, you could do two checks, like this:

```
select *
from FFTGGM.data_attributes_ext A
where 
EXISTS (
  select finished_good
  from FFTGGM.data_attributes_ext B
  where A.finished_good=B.finished_good
    and prodclass_cd = 'WU'
)
and 
EXISTS (
  select finished_good
  from FFTGGM.data_attributes_ext B
  where A.finished_good=B.finished_good
    and prodclass_cd <> 'WU'
)
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you. I was able to modify the 3rd slightly and get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do:

```
where prodclass_cd in (select distinct prodclass_cd from prodclasstable)
```

Your criteria in the WHERE clause can then be dynamic.